# Additional files get added when making a PR

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly new to using GIT. I'm having some issues when I make Pull Requests..

I create a branch called `branch1` and make a PR of let's say 4 files to my remote repo.

Now when I checkout another branch `branch2` from my `branch1` and create a PR for 2 more files, the previous 4 files get added into this PR as well.

Not sure how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you created the `branch2` from `branch1`, `branch2` contains  also the changes of `branch1` - this is visible in the PR.

You should create a "clean" branch, e.g. from `master` instead of `branch1`. Commit the changes and those will be fully separated from `branch1`, then the PR will have only those changes.

How to fix? Git rebase `branch2` on the main branch, e.g. `master`, and skip the unneeded commits (those from `branch1`)